# Seq.Map string->string

Tags: f#, dictionary, seq

all!

What is wrong with this code? I cannot understand what I am doing wrong with Seq.Map.
Here is the error message: The type 'unit' is not compatible with the type 'seq<'a>'

```
let getPathToLibFile value =
    let regex = new Regex("\"(?<data>[^<]*)\"")
    let matches = regex.Match(value)
    matches.Value

let importAllLibs (lines:string[]) =
    lines
    |> Seq.filter isImportLine
    |> Seq.iter (printfn "Libs found: %s")
    |> Seq.map getPathToLibFile // error in this line
    |> Seq.iter (printfn "Path to libs: %s")
```

Is there any understandable examples on Seq.Map?

PS Example from wiki (it works):

```
(* Fibonacci Number formula *)
let rec fib n =
    match n with
    | 0 | 1 -> n
    | _ -> fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2)

(* Print even fibs *)
[1 .. 10]
|> List.map     fib
|> List.filter  (fun n -> (n % 2) = 0)
|> printlist
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect the problem is *actually* your previous call.

[`Seq.iter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340396.aspx) doesn't return anything (or rather, returns `unit`) so you can't use it in the middle of a pipeline. Try this:

```
let importAllLibs (lines:string[]) =
    lines
    |> Seq.filter isImportLine
    |> Seq.map getPathToLibFile
    |> Seq.iter (printfn "Path to libs: %s")
```

... and then if you really need to print out the "libs found" line, you can add another mapping which performs the printing and just returns the input:

```
let reportLib value =
    printfn "Libs found: %s" value
    value

let importAllLibs (lines:string[]) =
    lines
    |> Seq.filter isImportLine
    |> Seq.map reportLib
    |> Seq.map getPathToLibFile
    |> Seq.iter (printfn "Path to libs: %s")
```

This may well be invalid F#, but I think the *aim* is right :)

Comment: @CKoenig: Does the `reportLib` function look okay to you? That's the bit I'm rather worried about :)

Comment: reportLib might want to be a method instead of a function. It won't execute more than once for a given input. But that may/may not be an issue for original poster.

Comment: @Rangoric: Oh, due to result caching? Interesting. I should really learn more about this F# business at some point...

Comment: @Jon Skeet It works, thank you. Didn't think that problem can be in Seq.Iter. P.S. reportLib is not really needed - I used it for debugging purposes.

Comment: @Stephen For a regular function in F#, it will cache the result so it doesn't have to execute more than once. To get it to execute more than once (typically for side effects such as the printfn) you need to use a method instead.

Comment: @Jon Yes, it looked like it was just debug information, and even then why list the same path 2x. Just so many things that screamed once is enough on the output. Seeing a side effect worries me when I see it in a function and I like to point out it will only happen once.

Comment: @Rangonic: F# is not a pure functional language and therefore does not presume to cache results of function calls. You need to explicitly use memoization to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

WebSharper includes an operator you can define yourself like this:

```
let (|!>) a f = f a; a
```

Allowing you to call a function of type `'a -> unit` on the input value returning the same value.

Fixing your code would require but a slight modification:

```
lines
|> Seq.filter isImportLine
|!> Seq.iter (printfn "Libs found: %s")
|> Seq.map getPathToLibFile // error in this line
|> Seq.iter (printfn "Path to libs: %s")
```

On the other hand you would end up iterating the collection twice which might not be what you want.

A better approach would be to define a function Do (lowercase `do` being a reserved keyword in F#) which introduces a side effect on iterating the sequence. Rx.NET (Ix) provides such a function in EnumerableEx:

```
let Do f xs = Seq.map (fun v -> f v; v) xs
```

and then you can introduce the side effect like so:

```
lines
|> Seq.filter isImportLine
|> Do (printfn "Libs found: %s")
|> Seq.map getPathToLibFile // error in this line
|> Seq.iter (printfn "Path to libs: %s")
```

The side effect will be introduced only upon iterating the collection on the last line.